# Como colocar pontos no início e final da palavra selecionada assim como as aspas são colocadas

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer para que o Sublime Text 3 adicione um ponto `.` no início e no fim da palavra que selecionei, da mesma forma que é feito com os caracteres `'` e `"`.

Quando selecionamos uma palavra no Sublime e apertamos no teclado o botão das aspas, simples ou duplas, em vez dele apagar a palavra e substituí-la pelas aspas (assim como é feito em outros editores), ele coloca uma aspa no início e no final no da palavra, exemplo:

`exemplo` => `'exemplo'`

Eu gostaria que quando eu selecionasse a palavra e apertasse o caractere ponto, `.`, que ele fizesse a mesma coisa:

`exemplo` => `.exemplo.`

Em vez de apagar a palavra e deixar apenas o ponto como a seguir `exemplo` = `.`.

Tentei procurar nas configurações e key_binding do Sublime, mas não achei.

O que eu posso fazer para acrescentar essa funcionalidade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta ir nas preferências de teclas de atalho: *Preferences* **→** *Key Bindings*.

Nas preferências *default* (editor do lado esquerdo) você verá que já existem opções de "*Auto-pair*" para as aspas, parênteses, etc. Então basta copiar uma delas para as suas preferências (editor do lado direito), mudando o caractere indicado para o ponto. Fica assim:

```js
{ "keys": ["."], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": ".$0."}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": false},
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "[.a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.single - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["."], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": ".${0:$SELECTION}."}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": false }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["."], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\.", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "punctuation.definition.string.begin", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.single - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["backspace"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "res://Packages/Default/Delete Left Right.sublime-macro"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\.$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\\.", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "punctuation.definition.string.begin", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.single - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true },
    ]
},
```

Basicamente, eu copiei uma das configurações existentes (peguei das aspas) e mudei as aspas para ponto: em `"keys": ["."]`, `"contents": ".$0."`, e outros lugares. Um detalhe é que em alguns pontos há expressões regulares, e por isso precisei escapar o ponto com `\` (já que [o ponto possui significado especial em regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) e é necessário fazer o escape). Mas como o valor está dentro de uma string, precisei escrever o `\` como `\\` (como em `"operand": "^\\."`, por exemplo).

Com isso, agora é possível colocar o ponto em volta do texto selecionado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Também mudei alguns valores de `true` para `false` (nas 2 primeiras configurações de `keys`):

```
{ "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": false}
```

Se deixar "operand" e "match_all" como `true`, ao digitar um único ponto (sem nenhum texto selecionado), ele coloca outro ponto logo depois (assim como acontece com as aspas ou parênteses, que ele automaticamente coloca o fechamento). Mudando para `false`, eu evito este comportamento.